# How can I copy to clipboard in HTML5 without using flash?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use a copy-to-clipboard function in HTML5, but without using flash. Is it possible? How?

I tried to implement a copy-to-clipboad function with JavaScript, but it is not working:

```
function Copytoclipboard() {
    var body = document.body,
        range, sel;
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
        range = document.createRange();
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        try {
            range.selectNodeContents(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
            document.execCommand('Copy');
        } catch (e) {
            range.selectNode(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
            document.execCommand('Copy');
        }
    } else if (body.createTextRange) {
        range = body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(el);
        range.select();
        range.execCommand('Copy');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use the `HTML5 clipboard api` http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/other/working-with-clipboard-apis-in-html5-web-apps.html#fbid=eh9tM7GHJWF

But do note that not all browsers fully support it as of now: http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard

Comment: "Not fully support" is one way to say it. Unusable is another. Chrome, Safari, Opera don't support the EventConstructor which seems essential if you want to copy anything to clipboard.

Comment: But it does answer the question. User asked for html5.

Comment: What about support for all the different browsers on mobile devices? There's a million of them.  It seems predictions that HTML5 was more about hype and broken promises have come true.  If we still can't get this simple micro-feature working consistently in 2015, are we going to all be retired before this stuff "just works"?  Maybe plug-in architecture wasn't so bad after all. Works great for Eclipse.

Comment: Love the way that html goodies don't include a working example. 5*

Answer (score 25):

**UPDATE:** This solution now works in the current version of all major browsers!

```js
function copyText(text){
  function selectElementText(element) {
    if (document.selection) {
      var range = document.body.createTextRange();
      range.moveToElementText(element);
      range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
      var range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNode(element);
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
      window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    }
  }
  var element = document.createElement('DIV');
  element.textContent = text;
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  selectElementText(element);
  document.execCommand('copy');
  element.remove();
}


var txt = document.getElementById('txt');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  copyText(txt.value);
})
```

```html
<input id="txt" />
<button id="btn">Copy To Clipboard</button>
```

Note: Trying to use this solution to copy an empty string or a string that is only whitespace will not work.

***ALTERNATE, SIMPLIFIED SOLUTION***

*This alternate solution has been tested in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.*

```js
const txt = document.querySelector('#txt')
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')

const copy = (text) => {
  const textarea = document.createElement('textarea')
  document.body.appendChild(textarea)
  textarea.value = text
  textarea.select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
  textarea.remove()
}

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  copy(txt.value)
})
```

```html
<input id="txt" />
<button id="btn">Copy</button>
```

Note: This solution will not copy an empty string, but it will copy whitespace.

Answer (score 17):

It's not working because it requires a user interaction such as click. Otherwise, `document.execCommand` will not work. You also might wanna check [clipboard.js](http://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/), it's a super easy library to copy text to clipboard that doesn't require Flash.

Comment: Not the relevant answer, but best approach. Upvoted.

Answer (score 16):

Function for inserting text into the clipboard:

```
function copyStringToClipboard (string) {
    function handler (event){
        event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', string);
        event.preventDefault();
        document.removeEventListener('copy', handler, true);
    }

    document.addEventListener('copy', handler, true);
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

Comment: FYI this will probably work on all today's browsers. For IE would work simple `window.clipboardData.setData("Text", string)`.

Comment: This is the best solution when you want to copy text which is not available in the DOM, e.g. an error message's stack trace.

Comment: @Petr Žoček, This sir is a stroke of absolute genius! I would love know where you learned this? It is the only solution I have found after a solid day of searching and trying many solutions and this is the only one that preserves style elements in the data and does not filter them out. You deserve a gold medal!

Answer (score 6):

If you don't care that the contents of the text field will be selected prior to copy, here is two-line solution that works at least in Chrome 56 and Edge, but I bet it works in other browsers as well.

```js
function clickListener() {
  document.getElementById('password').select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
}

document.getElementById('copy_btn').addEventListener('click', clickListener);
```

```html
<input id=password value="test">
<button id=copy_btn>Copy</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uwd0rm08/

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Clipboard.js TO add Copy to clipboard. This work without flash take a look on Code Which I use:

```js
//for copy to clickboard
var els = document.querySelectorAll('pre');
for (var i=0; i < els.length; i++) {
//for CLIPBOARD
var atr = els[i].innerHTML;
    els[i].setAttribute("data-clipboard-text", atr);
 //For SELECT
 var ids = "elementID"+[i]
    els[i].setAttribute("id", ids);
    els[i].setAttribute("onclick","selectText(this.id)");
 
}
    var btns = document.querySelectorAll('pre');
    var clipboard = new ClipboardJS(btns);

    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
  });

    clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
 
 //for select
 function selectText(id){
    var sel, range;
    var el = document.getElementById(id); //get element id
    if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) { //Browser compatibility
      sel = window.getSelection();
      if(sel.toString() == ''){ //no text selection
         window.setTimeout(function(){
            range = document.createRange(); //range object
            range.selectNodeContents(el); //sets Range
            sel.removeAllRanges(); //remove all ranges from selection
            sel.addRange(range);//add Range to a Selection.
        },1);
      }
    }else if (document.selection) { //older ie
        sel = document.selection.createRange();
        if(sel.text == ''){ //no text selection
            range = document.body.createTextRange();//Creates TextRange object
            range.moveToElementText(el);//sets Range
            range.select(); //make selection.
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<pre>I Have To Copy it<pre>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@2/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
```

To Know More About Its Usage visit Source :[html5 copy to clipboard](https://builtinbit.com/copy-to-clipboard.html)