# How do I copy an anchor element onclick?

Tags: javascript, email, onclick, copy

I'm trying to copy an anchor element (title) using onclick. This fires but doesn't copy the value. Any thoughts?

I know it's very rudimentary but, well, that's me.

```html
<a id="myAnchor" onclick="myFunction()" title="smarty@pants.com" href="#">smarty@pants.com</a>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("myAnchor").title;
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it differently, but since you want to use execCommand("Copy"), one way is to create a "mock" input element inside your click handler and select it:

```
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myAnchor").title;
  var mockInput = document.createElement("input");
  document.body.appendChild(mockInput);
  mockInput.type = "text";
  mockInput.value = copyText;
  mockInput.style.opacity = 0;
  mockInput.style.position = "absolute";
  mockInput.style.top = "0px";
  mockInput.style.left = "0px";
  mockInput.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
  mockInput.parentNode.removeChild(mockInput);
}
```

Now you "copied" to clipboard

Answer (score 1):

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/phj1wyqj/

> HTML:

```
<a id="myAnchor" title="smarty@pants.com" href="#">smarty@pants.com</a>
```

> JS Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myAnchor").title;
  document.addEventListener('copy', function(event) {
    event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', copyText);
    event.preventDefault();
    document.removeEventListener('copy', handler, true);
  }, true);
  document.execCommand('copy');
  alert("Copied: " + copyText);
}
document.getElementById('myAnchor').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

Ref: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336138/how-can-i-copy-to-clipboard-in-html5-without-using-flash)

Comment: **event.clipboardData.setData**
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData)

**document.execCommand('copy');**
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

Comment: Thank you so much :)