# How to copy text to clipboard HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set p element which contains a link. I would like for the user to click a button, and it gets the value of the p element and copies it to the user's clipboard.

```js
function copy() {
  document.getElementById("link").copy;
}
```

```css
#link {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p id="link" onclick="copy()">https://www.spotify.com/us/</p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I copy to clipboard in HTML5 without using flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336138/how-can-i-copy-to-clipboard-in-html5-without-using-flash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function copy() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("link").innerText;
  var elem = document.createElement("textarea");
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
  elem.value = copyText;
  elem.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(elem);
  alert("Copied the text");
}
```

```css
#link {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p id="link" onclick="copy()">https://www.spotify.com/us/</p>
```

Your copy function can be as follows

```
function copy() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("link").innerText;
  var elem = document.createElement("textarea");
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
  elem.value = copyText;
  elem.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(elem);
  alert("Copied the text");
}
```

Comment: Could you please give a go at my edited answer? Thanks!

Comment: TYSM! I was looking for a short and straightforward answer and you really helped!

Answer (score 0):

try this as the copy function

```
var text =  document.getElementById("link");
text.select();
document.execCommand("copy);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `input` to copy text on clipboard

```js
function copy() {
    /* Get the text field */
    var copyText = document.getElementById("link");

    /* Select the text field */
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/

    /* Copy the text inside the text field */
    document.execCommand("copy");
    console.log("copied!");
}
```

```html
<input id="link" onclick="copy()" value="https://www.spotify.com/us/">
```

Or if you want to use p then yuo can use this trick

```js
function copy() {
    /* Get the text field */
    var copyText = document.getElementById("link");
    var copyP = document.getElementById("link_p");
    copyText.value=copyP.innerHTML;

    /* Select the text field */
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/

    /* Copy the text inside the text field */
    document.execCommand("copy");
    console.log("copied!");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="link" value="" style="display:none">
<p id="link_p" onclick="copy()">text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function copy() {
  document.getElementById("link").copy;
}
```

```css
#link {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p id="link" onclick="copy()">https://www.spotify.com/us/</p>
```